# How to add styles to jquery in an object?

Tags: jquery

How to add styles to an object with jquery?

I have this code:

```
$('<p></p>', {
    text: 'MyText',
    class: 'MyClass',
    // What can I use also to add styles like font-size:30px to that paragraph?
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as every property you have added in that `object`, just add another one property to it as `style`,

```
$('<p></p>', {
    text: 'MyText',
    class: 'MyClass',
    style:'font-size:30px;'
});
```

Or you could do the same with with [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). So the code becomes more readable and maintainable.

```
$('<p></p>', {
    text: 'MyText',
    class: 'MyClass'
}).css('font-size','30px');
```

Comment: Why I haven't think about that !! I tried css: and it didn't work that's why I was confused. Thank you so much for this easy/quick answer.

Comment: @JoJo `.css()` should work. Not sure how did you use that. Anyway glad to help!

Comment: I used it within the object like this (css: 'font-size:30px;') and not the way you have in your comment. Anyway Thanks Again :)